# How to embedded a Google Analytics widget that is restricted to a single URL?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm working on a sort of image hosting website where each uploaded image has its own page and unique URL. Within that page, I would like to display an analytics graph/widget which would display how many visitors visited the page in the past week or month.

I'm already using Google Analytics for the whole website so it would be nice if I could just pull out data for that specific URL out from Google Analytics and display it in a graph.

I noticed GA already has an embed API (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/) but it doesn't seem to be possible to restrict the graph data to a single URL.

Any suggestions (including third party services or alternatives to GA) on how to achieve this quickly and securely would help greatly.

Comment: It is perfectly possible to restrict the results of the embed API to a single Url. However the embed API requires authorization, so everyone who wants to see the data needs to have access to the GA account in the first place, that's probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, it seems the only secure way to do this is to pull out the data server side using the Google Analytics API and build my own custom graph widgets (e.g. using Google Charts) on the client.